# Get constants in array from child class in php

Tags: php, inheritance, reflection, constants

i have following problem. I have child class which contains only constants. I have variable constants in parent class. I need get constants as variable in parent class.
I try

```
$onClass = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
$this->constants = $onClass->getConstants();
```

But this behaves only if I call this in child constructor. I need call this in parent construnctor. Is there any possibilites how to do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: if it is constant, cant you access it by just calling it?

Comment: I don't think there's any such thing as "variable constants"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation simply goes against the inheritance model. You might need to consider a refactor.

This is what it sounds like your current setup is:

```
class A {
    function __construct() {
        $this->constants = $this->getConstants()
    }
}

class B extends A {
  public function getConstants() {
      return [1, 2, 3];
  }
}
```

You will not be able to call getConstants from within the Class A declaration. Class A does not have such a function defined, and it also does not know (or care) whether or not it is an instance of Class B.

It almost sounds like you have your hierarchy reversed:

```
class A extends B {
    public $constants;
    function __construct() {
        $this->constants = $this->getConstants()
    }
}

class B {
  public function getConstants() {
      return [1, 2, 3];
  }
}
```